# does abybody know the meaning of the following code snippet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

does abybody know the meaning of the following code snippet?

```
define insist(e) 
if(!(e)) 
    [NSException raise: @"assertion failed." format: @"%@:%d (%s)", [[NSString stringWithCString:__FILE__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] lastPathComponent], __LINE__, #e]
```

Answer (score 0):

It defines a macro for exception handling. If `e` is nil, an exception will be raised with file, line and which variable failed the test.